# The units of $\mathbb Z[\sqrt{2}]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

> How can I show that the units $u$ of $R=\mathbb Z[\sqrt{2}]$ with $u>1$ are $(1+ \sqrt{2})^{n}$ ?

I have proved that the right ones are units because their module is one, and it is said to me to do it by induction on $b$ and multiplication by $-1+\sqrt{2}$. I have already shown that the units of this ring has norm $1$ and all the numbers with norm $1$ are units, this may help.

Comment: Since this is equivalent with finding integer solutions of a specific Pell's equation $x²-2y²=1$, it could be done by use of continued fractions expansion of $\sqrt2$. In addition, this question is also equivalent with determining the rank of a peculiar quadratic number ring, which should involve some cohomological calculations and some genus theory(or not?). In any case, I see no reason not to tag the number-theory tag...

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continued_fraction See its theorem 3

Comment: @awllower Actually, it is equivalent to finding solutions to$x^2-2y^2=\pm 1$. Indeed, $1+\sqrt{2}$ corresponds to such a solution for $x^2-2y^2=-1$

Comment: @awllower, I would like to read about the relations you mentioned above. I realized that it has been 4 years but still I appreciate if you could answer.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

First, note that $a+b\sqrt{2}$ is a unit if and only if $a^2-2b^2=\pm1$. Use that to show that if $b\neq 0$ then $|b|\leq |a|< 2|b|$.

Now we first restrict ourselves to $a,b\geq 0$, and prove by induction on $b$.

If $b=0$ then $a=\pm 1$, and $u>0$ implies $a=1$, so $u=(1+\sqrt 2)^0$.

If $a,b>0$ and $a+b\sqrt{2}$ is a unit, then $$(a+b\sqrt{2})(\sqrt{2}-1) = (2b-a)+(a-b)\sqrt{2}$$
is also a unit.

Since we know that $b\leq a< 2b$ and $b<a$,  we have that $2b-a>0$ and $0<a-b<b$, so by induction:

$$(a+b\sqrt{2})(\sqrt{2}-1) =(1+\sqrt{2})^n$$

But multiplying both sides by $1+\sqrt{2}$ you get:

$$a+b\sqrt{2}=(1+\sqrt{2})^{n+1}$$

Then you have to deal with the case where one of $a,b$ is negative...

Comment: $a+b\sqrt(2)$ is a unit if and only if $a^2−2b^2|a$ and $a^2−2b^2|b$; why does this imply $a^2−2b^2=±1$?

Comment: thomas Whhy is it so?

Comment: @Temitope.A If $a+b\sqrt{2}$ is a unit, show that $a-b\sqrt{2}$ is also a unit, so $a^2-2b^2=(a+b\sqrt{2})(a-b\sqrt{2})$ is a unit. But the only elements of $\mathbb Z$ that are units in $\mathbb Z[\sqrt{2}]$ are $\pm 1$

Comment: @Temitope.A Alternatively, you could show directly that if $a,b$ are not relatively prime, then $a+b\sqrt{2}$ cannot be a unit.

Comment: Let $a+b \sqrt{2}$ be a unit. To show $a^2-2b^2=\pm 1$, define $N(a+b \sqrt{2}):=a^2-2b^2$.  It can be verified that $N(\alpha \beta)=N(\alpha)N(\beta), \forall \alpha, \beta \in \mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{2}]$.  If $\alpha=a+b \sqrt{2}$ is a unit, then $\alpha \beta=1$ for some $\beta$, whence $N(\alpha)N(\beta)=1$ in $\mathbb{Z}$. Thus, $N(\alpha)=\pm 1$.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Where'd you get $(\sqrt 2 -1)$?

Comment: Given that this answer is more than two years old, please be more specific if you have questions. @AlJebr

Comment: @AlJebr I know it has been a longtime but for future reader, I want to add the answer for your question . Note that $N(\sqrt{2}-1)=1^2-2=-1$. So $\sqrt{2}-1$ is  a unit. Since multiplication of units is a unit, if $a+b\sqrt{2}$ is a unit, $(a+b\sqrt{2})(\sqrt{2}-1)$ is a unit.

Comment: Excellent! It takes effort to follow your reasonings, but the whole idea and arguments are there. Thanks!!

Answer (score 9):

Here is a simpler proof that relies only on basic bounding arguments. Note that if $u$ is a unit then $u, 1/u, -u, -1/u$ are all units also. Now, since once of these is greater than $1$, it suffices to show if $u<1$ then $u$ is a power of $1+\sqrt{2}$. Clearly the nonnegative powers of $1+\sqrt{2}$ monotonically tend to $\infty$ starting from $1$, so we can write $$(1+\sqrt{2})^k\le u <(1+\sqrt{2})^{k+1}$$ for some $k\in\mathbf{Z}^{+}\cup\{0\}$. Dividing by $(1+\sqrt{2})^k$ yields $$1\le u(1+\sqrt{2})^{-k}<1+\sqrt{2}.$$ Note that $u(1+\sqrt{2})^{-k}\in\mathbf{Z}[\sqrt{2}]^{\times}$, and since $1+\sqrt{2}$ is the smallest unit greater than $1$, we must have $u(1+\sqrt{2})^{-k}=1\implies u=(1+\sqrt{2})^k$. Due to norm being multiplicative, all powers of $1+\sqrt{2}$ are units, so we are done.

Comment: How do you get that $1+\sqrt{2}$ is the smallest unit greater than 1?

Comment: Let $\eta$ be a unit in $\mathbb{Z[\sqrt2]}$, say of the form $\eta = a + b \sqrt2$ which is assumed to be greater than $1.$ Then, since $N(\eta) = \pm 1$, we have $-1 < a - b\sqrt2< 1$. Suppose $\eta < 1 + \sqrt2$. Adding the two inequalities yields $0<2a<2+\sqrt2$, and since $a$ is an integer, a must be 1. We have a contradiction to $\eta < 1 + \sqrt2$, since there is no integer b satisfying this.