# If α is a unit in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt2]$ then $a^2 - 2b^2 = \pm1$

Tags: ring-theory

$$\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt2]  = \{a + b√2: a,b \in \mathbb{Z}\}$$

The question is asking to prove that if $\alpha$ is a unit in this set, then:
$$a^2 - 2b^2 = \pm1$$
I've hit a dead end already:
[image: Attempt at proof]

I wanted to use the fact that there must exist another element in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt2]$ such that $\alpha\beta = 1$.

Now I'm lost, since I've just accidentally shown that the difference of $a^2$ and $2b^2$ should be equal to $1$, not that they are both equal to $1$.  Am I going about this the wrong way?

Comment: Are you familiar with norm (in this context)?

Comment: I am not familiar with norm.  What is it exactly?

Comment: Are you sure the question's written properly? How can $2b^2 = 1$ if $b \in \mathbb Z$?

Comment: I'm starting to think that it is a typo in the question.  I cannot figure this out for the life of me lol.

Comment: The norm of $a+b\sqrt{2}$, in this ring, is $a^2-2b^2$. A quick characterization of units can be given by verifying that the norm of a product is the product of the norms (Brahmagupta Identity).  And your question should say $a^2-2b^2=\pm 1$, or something equivalent.

Comment: Thank you so much, André!  I'll look into it now.

Comment: Let me add an element is a unit if and only if its norm is a unit in $\mathbf Z$, i.e. is equal to $\pm1$.

Comment: Many thanks, Bernard.

Comment: @Bernard You see, it is important to precise it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [The units of $\mathbb Z[\sqrt{2}]$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/280878/the-units-of-mathbb-z-sqrt2). See also http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/438913/determine-all-units-of-the-domain-mathbbz-sqrt2?rq=1.

Comment: @DietrichBurde: The linked questions are harder, for there one is asked to describe the units explicitly. For this question, one does not need to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Since $(1+\sqrt{2})(-1+\sqrt{2})=1$, we see that $\pm (1+\sqrt{2})^n$ is a unit for all $n\in \mathbb{Z}$. Using the norm it is easy to see that every unit in $\mathbb{Z} [\sqrt{2}]^{\times}$ is of this form. In fact $\alpha=a+b\sqrt{2}$ is a unit iff $N(\alpha)=a^2-2b^2=\pm 1$.