# What is the pattern in the powers of $\sqrt{2}-\sqrt{1}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory, pattern-recognition

What is the pattern in this?

$$\begin{align}
\left(\sqrt{2}-\sqrt{1}\right)^1 &= \sqrt{2}-\sqrt{1}\\
\left(\sqrt{2}-\sqrt{1}\right)^2 &= \sqrt{9}-\sqrt{8}\\
\left(\sqrt{2}-\sqrt{1}\right)^3 &= \sqrt{50}-\sqrt{49}\\
\left(\sqrt{2}-\sqrt{1}\right)^4 &= \sqrt{289}-\sqrt{288}\\
\end{align}$$

I thought of applying the binomial theorem

Comment: The group of units of $\Bbb Z[\sqrt{2}]$ gives the answer, i.e., solving a Pell equation - see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1127003/if-%ce%b1-is-a-unit-in-mathbbz-sqrt2-then-a2-2b2-pm1?noredirect=1&lq=1). Please don't use pictures.
See [here](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text), why.
Use MathJax. Here is a
[tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Yes, you could use the binomial theorem. Separate the cases of $n$ even and $n$ odd. For $n=2m$, for example, you get $(\sqrt{2}-1)^{2m}=\sum_{k=0}^{2m}\binom{2m}{k}2^{k/2}(-1)^{2m-k}$. You can split the sum into the terms with $k$ odd $-B=-\sum_{r=0}^{m-1}\binom{2m}{2r+1}2^{r}\sqrt{2}$ and those with $k$ even $A=\sum_{r=0}^{m}\binom{2m}{2r}2^{r}$. So, you get $(\sqrt{2}-1)^{2m}=\sqrt{A^2}-\sqrt{B^2}$. You can do something similar for the case of $n$ odd.

Comment: So by the known solutions to Pell's equation $a^2-2b^2=\pm 1$ we obtain $(\sqrt{2}-1)^2=3-2\sqrt{2}=\sqrt{9}-\sqrt{8}$, $(\sqrt{2}-1)^3=-7+5\sqrt{2}=\sqrt{50}-\sqrt{49}$, and so on.

Comment: See also https://oeis.org/A115599

Comment: Quite possibly prompted by a [Michael Penn video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l-I0PUsob_E) posted just a little earlier this week.

Comment: Maybe https://oeis.org/A055997?

Answer (score 2):

Given that

$$\left(\sqrt{2}-\sqrt{1}\right)^k = \sqrt{A_k}-\sqrt{A_k-1}$$

then

$$\left(\sqrt{2}-\sqrt{1}\right)^{k+1} = \left(\sqrt{2}-\sqrt{1}\right)(\sqrt{A_k}-\sqrt{A_k-1})=\\=\sqrt 2\sqrt{A_k}-\sqrt 2\sqrt{A_k-1}-\sqrt{A_k}+\sqrt{A_k-1}=$$

$$=\sqrt{A_{k+1}}-\sqrt{A_{k+1}-1}$$

with

- $\sqrt{A_{k+1}}=\sqrt 2\sqrt{A_k}+\sqrt{A_k-1} \implies A_{k+1}=3A_k-1+2\sqrt2\sqrt{A_k(A_k-1)}$
- $\sqrt{A_{k+1}-1}=\sqrt 2\sqrt{A_k-1}+\sqrt{A_k}\implies A_{k+1}=3A_k-1+2\sqrt2\sqrt{A_k(A_k-1)}$

that is

> $$A_{k+1}=3A_k-1+2\sqrt2\sqrt{A_k(A_k-1)}$$

and $A_1=2$.

---

Using an approach similar to [this one](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1631238p10240851), we have

$$A_{k+1}=3A_k-1+2\sqrt2\sqrt{A_k(A_k-1)} \\\iff 2A_{k+1}-1=3(2A_{k}-1)+2\sqrt2\sqrt{(2A_k-1)^2-1}$$

and by $2A_{k+1}-1=\frac12\left(t_k+\frac1{t_k}\right) \implies t_1=3+2\sqrt 2$ we obtain

$$t_{k+1}+\frac1{t_{k+1}}=3\left(t_k+\frac1{t_k}\right)+2\sqrt 2\sqrt{\left(t_k+\frac1{t_k}\right)^2-4}$$

$$t_{k+1}+\frac1{t_{k+1}}=3\left(t_k+\frac1{t_k}\right)+2\sqrt 2\left(t_k-\frac1{t_k}\right)$$

$$t_{k+1}+\frac1{t_{k+1}}=(3+2\sqrt 2)t_k+\frac{3-2\sqrt 2}{t_k}$$

$$t_{k+1}+\frac1{t_{k+1}}=(3+2\sqrt 2)t_k+\frac{1}{(3+2\sqrt 2)t_k}$$

$$t_{k}=(3+2\sqrt 2)^k$$

and then

> $$A_k=\frac{(3+2\sqrt 2)^k+(3-2\sqrt 2)^k+2}{4}$$

Comment: Is it obvious from here that $A_k$ is integer?

Comment: @leonbloy I've added a derivation which shows this.

Answer (score 2):

If $(\sqrt 2  - 1)^n  = \sqrt {a_n }  - \sqrt {a_n  - 1}$, then $
(\sqrt 2  + 1)^n  = \sqrt {a_n }  + \sqrt {a_n  - 1}$. Hence,
$$
a_n  = \left( {\frac{{(\sqrt 2  + 1)^n  + (\sqrt 2  - 1)^n }}{2}} \right)^2  = \frac{{2 + (3 + 2\sqrt 2 )^n  + (3 - 2\sqrt 2 )^n }}{4}.
$$
This is [A115599](https://oeis.org/A115599) in the OEIS. See also [A055997](https://oeis.org/A055997). You can show using the binomial theorem that $a_n$ is always an integer. In fact $$
a_n  = \frac{{3^n  + 1}}{2} + \sum\limits_{k = 1}^{\left\lfloor {n/2} \right\rfloor } \binom{n}{2k}2^{3k - 1} 3^{n - 2k}  . 
$$

Comment: This approach seems more much effective and clever than mine! ;)

Answer (score 2):

We have $$(\sqrt{1}-\sqrt{2})^k = \sqrt{a_k^2} - \sqrt{2b_k^2}$$
where $a_k,b_k$ obey the following recurrence relationships:
$$a_{k+1}=a_{k}+2b_{k}\\
b_{k+1}=a_{k}+b_{k}$$
with $a_{1}=1$ and  $b_1 = 1$.  This can be proved inductively. To understand the recurrence relationship we can recast it as a matrix equation:
$${\begin{pmatrix}
a_{k+1}\\
b_{k+1}
\end{pmatrix}} = \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2 \\
1 & 1 
\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}
a_k\\
b_k
\end{pmatrix} $$

The eigenvectors are $\begin{pmatrix}
\sqrt{2} \\
1 
\end{pmatrix}$, $\begin{pmatrix}
\sqrt{2} \\
-1 
\end{pmatrix}$ with coresponding eigenvalues: $1+\sqrt{2}$ and $1-\sqrt{2}$. 
This allows us to solve:
$${\begin{pmatrix}
a_{n}\\
b_{n}
\end{pmatrix}} = {\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2 \\
1 & 1 
\end{pmatrix}}^{n-1} \begin{pmatrix}
1\\
1
\end{pmatrix} $$ with: $$a_{n} = \frac{(1+\sqrt{2})^n + (1-\sqrt{2})^n}{2}\\
b_{n} = \frac{(1+\sqrt{2})^n - (1-\sqrt{2})^n}{2\sqrt{2}}$$

A recurrence relationship can also be written for each term separately as:

$$a_{n} = 2a_{n-1} + a_{n-2}\\
b_{n} = 2 b_{n-1} + b_{n-2}$$

with starting terms $a_1 = 1$, $a_2 = 3$, $b_1 = 1$, $b_2 = 2$.

We can write it as a recurrence relationship or a matrix equation if we wish to use only integers, or we can write the terms individually, but that causes the reappearance of $\sqrt{2}$ in the formula.