# units in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{2}]$

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

I have question about the exercise in Neukirch book. I think i can prove that if there exist one unit number in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{2}]$ we can product infinite unit number in this way;
If  $m + n \sqrt{2}$ is unit then we have $m^2 - 2n^2 = 1 $ then by feremat theorem in case $n=2$ we have this another unit element $ (m^2 + 2n^2) + (2mn)\sqrt{2} $ because we have

$$ (m^2 + 2n^2)^2 + 2(2mn)^2 = (m^2 - 2n^2)^2 = 1  $$

by this proces we have that $ 3 + 2\sqrt{2} $ is unit $ (3 + 2\sqrt{2})(3 - 2\sqrt{2}) = 1 $
Is this deduction wrong? Or this forms of units are in form $\pm (1+\sqrt{2})^n$ ?

Comment: Comparing with [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/280878/the-units-of-mathbb-z-sqrt2) should answer your questions.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  Are you aware that $(3+2\sqrt2)=(1+\sqrt2)^2$?